# Datatable search is not applying

Tags: jquery, datatables

HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="heading">ID</th>
        <th class="heading">Create Date</th>
        <th class="heading">Client Name</th>
        <th class="heading">Company Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Create Date</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#example th.heading').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});
table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('th.heading > input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone can please tell me Datable making search input properly. But when I am Keyup or change then search is not working. How can I resolve this issue? Sorry for my weak English. Thanks in advance. Edit question so it may help for other users.

Comment: This is not a datatable implementation. Why not just implement datatable, rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Step 1: Press F12 and see if there are any javascript errors

Comment: it's a simple table refer https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html